# Limitations to using .NET framework and Visual Studio while not having administrator access in Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-7, 64-bit

Are there functionality limitations to using the Microsoft .NET framework and Visual Studio if you do not have administrator access to the box they are installed on?  If there aren't, what needs to be configured to have full functionality?  I hope this doesn't result in some lengthy answer.  If you think it is, let me know in the comments so I can post in a different place and delete my question.

We currently use Visual Studio 2010, but we will be moving to Visual Studio 2012 soon.

Comment: You don't need to run Visual Studio as an administrator to accomplish 98% of tasks.  You might occasionally need administrative rights.  The only thing that comes to mind is using IIS Express in debug mode listening to external requests (as opposed to only listening on localhost).

Comment: Dude, don't lie to people. Your name is not MacGyver.. it's Richard Dean Anderson.. :P

Comment: @HighCore, it's my alias ;-)

Comment: I agree with @TrevorElliott... I run VS 2012 not as an Admin and the only thing I've ever needed Admin rights for was for doing exactly what he mentioned.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/12/03/visual-studio-permissions-needed-on-windows-vista-or-later-vstipenv0056.aspx

Comment: Did one of you want to answer this one, so I don't leave this question unaccepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Visual Studio runs as an Administrator, there are not any limitations.  But this is dangerous because it has access to the entire operating system.

When installing Visual Studio with non admin rights, Visual Studio will run as the application pool identity with minimal rights.  This security group needs to be added to a folder in Windows in order to give the IDE rights to access it.

If Visual Studio needs to access IIS, it will not have enough rights as a non admin.  At the time, I wrote an application that sits between Visual Studio and Windows.  It used .NET code to interact with IIS because our company did not allow anyone to use administrator rights.  This way a developer could develop a localhost application before moving it to testing with our continuous integration.  Basically I had a Windows Forms application that communicated with a Windows service that I developed.  The Windows service had admin rights and changed the settings.  The client to the Windows service was using the local user and sent TCP messages to the Windows service.  My company allowed this.